# Frontend Rendering Error in Chrome with Next.js

Tags: next.js

Currently working on a complex frontend application. I've recently encountered a problem that seems to be exclusive to Chrome and I'm hoping someone here can provide some insight.

The issue arises when I attempt to execute a specific interaction (e.g. opening a modal, dragging and dropping an item, etc.). The interaction triggers a JavaScript error in Chrome but works as expected in other browsers like Firefox and Safari.

```
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  function handleOpen() {
    setIsOpen(true);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleOpen}>Open Modal</button>
      {isOpen && (
        <div>
          <h2>Modal Content</h2>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Error in chrome console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'handleOpen')
```

Despite various debugging attempts, including re-checking all related JavaScript code, inspecting elements and network traffic, and clearing the cache, the problem persists.

The code works flawlessly in other browsers, leading me to believe this could be a bug within Next.js itself or a Chrome-specific issue.

Any help would be appreciated!